# Faster alternative to populating a pre-allocated data frame using a for-loop

Tags: r, performance, simulation, memory-efficient

I am running a few different Monte Carlo simulations, all of which involve generating some data, fitting a model, and capturing several output variables from the fit of the model. Typically data are generated so that several characteristics vary (e.g., number of items, sample size), and models are fit so that several other characteristics vary (e.g., estimation method, model misspecification). I have no questions about generating the data or about how to actually fit the model. However, I know my method for populating my results data frame is very inefficient and I would like some help in improving this. My usual method is as follows:

1) Create data frame with as many rows as models I have to fit (e.g., number of iterations * different item lengths * different sample size lengths * different estimation methods * different types of model misspecification), and as many columns as I need to contain the identifying variables (sample size, number of items, etc.) and to capture all the output.

2) Use a for-loop to identify the particular combination of conditions and the particular iteration of said combination, fit the model, and populate the appropriate row of the data frame.

So I might start with something that looks like:

```
> head(df)
    fit.model n.sample n.item distr.cond estim iteration df.chisq obt.chisq
1           1      100      3          1    ML         1       NA        NA
1.1         1      100      3          1    ML         2       NA        NA
1.2         1      100      3          1    ML         3       NA        NA
1.3         1      100      3          1    ML         4       NA        NA
1.4         1      100      3          1    ML         5       NA        NA
1.5         1      100      3          1    ML         6       NA        NA
```

where the last two columns capture results and need to be filled in, and the first six columns are necessary to identify each row uniquely. I then use a for-loop to go row-by-row, pick out the identifying characteristics of that iteration (which allows me to locate the appropriate data file and read it in, as well as to specify how to fit the model), do the model fitting, and then write to the `NA` columns the output desired. Then I just fill in the remaining `NA`s with the obtained values, for instance using `df$obt.chisq[i] <- fitMeasures(fit,"chisq")`, where the function `fitMeasures` extracts the particular value from the resulting fitted model `fit`.

Is it possible to vectorize this? I forget the terminology, but I recognize that in this case each iteration is completely independent of each other iteration, so that the particular order doesn't matter. It's time for a change in approach! Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: lineprof (https://github.com/hadley/lineprof) is a package for profiling your code on a line by line basis.  I am saying this b/c my initial reaction is that when doing a bunch of model fitting, sticking the results in a preallocated data.frame doesn't seem like it should be the time sink.

Comment: That's what I thought too, but is it possible that I am forcing R to somehow look through or "handle" in some way this object that is growing larger and larger, which accounts for the slow-down as time passes? I will look at the package. Regardless, I would still like to find a better way to do what I described above.

Comment: You can always split the job over n CPU cores using the **parallel** package, which ships with R. You can't vectorise this in the sense of `+` or some other vectorised function. You could `lapply()` to get rid of the loop at R level but it's still there. Parallelising the job is one solution to running multiple rows from the `df` at once.

Comment: I use `expand.grid` to create the combinations and output them in a data.frame (that might be faster, or at least more concise, for the preallocation phase). I would then look to one of the functions in the  `apply` family. From there, parallelizing also makes sense. If the function accept all of the arguments can accept a vector, then you could be faster than `apply` (family) by just supplying each argument as a vector, right?

Comment: The problem I always had with the `apply` functions was figuring out how to get it to write multiple values to multiple slots in the data frame. That's probably just my own inexperience using the function, but it can do that, right? I mean using something like `df[,7:8] <- lapply(<some index>,function(x))` where the index specifies each row of the data frame and `function(x)` is everything I need to do in that iteration?